# scrollTo method cannot keep going down to app long page bottom, stop at the middle page

Tags: android, appium

My scenario is on Android app, there is a "Terms & Conditions" screen,  (there is no go to bottom button), and the page is super long.

When I using the following scrollTo method, screen is scrolling down, but after 30 turns, in the middle of "Term & Conditions" page, session exits, and got error report, cannot find the bottom ideal checkbox to accept the Terms & Condition.

Is there any solution to keep scrollTo method continue going down to the bottom? 
I have set this "capabilities.setCapability("appWaitDuration", 900000);"
And add "Thread.sleep(6000);", but still not working.  It is not able to continue scroll down to the page bottom, then session exited.

public void scrollTo(String text)
{
driver.findElementByAndroidUIAutomator("new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().scrollable(true).instance(0)).scrollIntoView(new UiSelector().textContains(\""+text+"\").instance(0))");
}

Comment: Looks like session timeout during scrolling down.  How to increase session waiting time.  I have changed capabilities.setCapability("appWaitDuration", 30000000); but useless.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found solution, run Touchaction 90 steps then scroll down to the bottom page.  See my code:

```html
Dimension size = driver.manage().window().getSize();
   int starty = (int) (size.height*0.9);
   int endy = (int) (size.height*0.2);
   int startx = (int)(size.width/2);
   
   do
   {
   try
   {
    checkBox.click();
   break;
   }
   catch(Exception e)
   {
    for(int i=1;i<=90;i++) {
      (new TouchAction(driver)).longPress(point(startx, starty)).moveTo(point(startx, endy)).release().perform();
      
    }
     (new TouchAction(driver)).longPress(point(startx, starty)).moveTo(point(startx, endy)).release().perform();
     
   }
   } while(true);
```